# How can I use Twilio sms notifcations in a web form?

Tags: html, webforms, sms, twilio

Can anyone tell me how I can us Twilio sms notifications in a web form so when someone fills out the form with their phone number I receive a sms which includes the phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here. You probably want to do this on the server side, otherwise you will have your Twilio credentials exposed to the world and his dog in the page source, which would be bad.

Then, when the page is submitted you just need to use your language of choice to make a call to the [Twilio REST API](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) with a [helper library](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries). Or, you can make a request without a helper library, this [example shows how to send an SMS](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms).

The SMS you send yourself can include anything you want, including the phone number submitted on the website.

Hope this helps!